# How to get rid of warning C4244/C4267 conversion?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, winsock2

Is it possible to get rid of compiler warnings trying to cast from `SOCKET` to `int` or from `size_t` to `int` using winsock2 functions like `sendto`, `select` etc? May there is a common approach? (Windows, MSVC15)

example:

C4267 conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data:

`sendto(_socket, managedPtr, _bufferSize, NULL, PSOCKADDR(&_sockaddr), sizeof(_sockaddr))`
____________________________________________________________~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C4244 conversion from 'SOCKET' to 'int', possible loss of data:

`select(_socket + 1, &readfds, nullptr, nullptr, GetTV())`

_______~~~~~~~~~______________________________________

Comment: What would happen if the return value of sendto which is size_t cannot be represented with an int? That is a narrowing conversion and has implementation defined behavior, hence the warning.

Comment: You understood me wrong, I'm not talking about the return value of winsock2 functions. Its all about argument conversion and common approach with casting types to windows types or about using size_t in those functions correctly without warnings.

Comment: These functions are ancient and date from much simpler times.  Casting bufferSize to (int) is required to keep the compiler happy about it.  Incrementing the socket is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

```
SOCKET s;
int i = static_cast<int>(s);
```

For the functions taking an `int` just make sure your value isn't `> std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and it should be ok to do `static_cast<int>(value)`.

```
sendto(_socket, managedPtr, _bufferSize, NULL,
       &_sockaddr, static_cast<int>(sizeof(_sockaddr)));

select(static_cast<int>(_socket)+1, ...); // the nfds parameter is ignored on Windows
```

Comment: In select function, you need to increment socket(warning C4244), in other winsock2 functions common type for size is int instead of size_t - so on different builds x64/x86 there would be warning C4267.

Comment: @SmitYcyken [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) states that the first parameter is ignored anyway so what is `_socket+1` supposed to do?

Comment: The first parameter should be set to the highest-numbered file descriptor plus 1.

Comment: No, the first argument to `select` is the number of sockets you have in your `fd_set`s, but it is ignored in Winsock2 as @Yastanub said.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, it needed to keep support for Unix Berkeley sockets.

Comment: Is this really going to be compiled on anything but Windows? I just noticed i was wrong about the number of sockets in the sets. It's actuallly supposed to be what you said. So, `static_cast<int>(_socket)+1` should work if `_socket` contains the highest numbered descriptor in the sets. Check BSD / Posix for compatibility issues. Especially the `BUGS` section.

Comment: Did you manage to get the warnings to go away by casting as shown above?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I had to use #define for select as the first parameter depending on the platform. Static casting from bigger types to smaller can lead to narrowing conversion, but it fixed warning 4244.

Comment: `#define` sounds like something you shouldn't need. What platforms are you compiling this on? What does the `#define` do?
You don't risk anything by doing the `static_cast<int>(_socket)`. On platforms where the `nfds` parameter matters, _socket will be a positive number that fits in an `int`. On Windows, it can theoretically loose information but that doesn't matter since the parameter is not used.

Answer (score 0):

**sendTo**: The compiler possibly warns you about this, because you try to build a 64 bit application. Thus, `size_t` would be a 64 bit wide type and int would be 32 bit at most. To resolve this try to cast the result explicitely to an `int` so the compiler knows this was intended. Also this function may be replaced by `send` as read here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto) "The sendto function is normally used on a connectionless socket to send a datagram to a specific peer socket identified by the to parameter. Even if the connectionless socket has been previously connected to a specific address, the to parameter overrides the destination address for that particular datagram only. On a connection-oriented socket, the to and tolen parameters are ignored, making sendto equivalent to [send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send)." so maybe check that too.

**select**: as [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) states the first parameter is ignored but kept as compatibility to berkeley sockets. Apparently Microsoft wanted to provide easy code portability to UNIX systems and thus designed its API to fit the POSIX standard so code can almost just be copy pasted (with some slight changes obviously) [Read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock#Technology). So if you use `winsock2` Ignore this parameter and set it to `0` or whatever integer. If you want to port your App, copy your code and pass a file descriptor of a socket instead of `0`.